# Rotate both image and ROI when image is a rectangle

Tags: python, image, opencv, math, computer-vision

I have this program in which when the user presses the up arrow key the image rotates 90º clockwise and when it presses the down arrow key the image rotates 90º counter-clockwise. This image has a region of interest (in blue), and after the image rotation, the ROI should be rotated in the same wayl - which I was actually able to pull off when the image is upside down... but not when the image is sideways.

[image: stack_overflow_cv2_question]

Since the image is a rectangle, when it is flipped sideways the aspect ratio gets inverted, and then the logic and the math gets a lot more complicated and I'm not being able to figure it out. The program is shown below and I've tried my best to comment everything relevant - where help is really needed is at the **rotate_point function** and the **middle section of the display_image function**.

```
import os
import cv2
import keyboard
import numpy as np

current_dir = os.getcwd() # Get the current working directory.

rotation_angle = 0 # Rotation angle of the image - initial rotation angle is obviously 0.
engine_img = None # Placeholder for the image.

# Function to rotate a point (x, y) around the image's center (cx, cy) by a given angle.
def rotate_point(cx, cy, x, y, angle):
    angle_rad = np.deg2rad(angle)
    x_rot = (x - cx) * np.cos(angle_rad) - (y - cy) * np.sin(angle_rad) + cx
    y_rot = (x - cx) * np.sin(angle_rad) + (y - cy) * np.cos(angle_rad) + cy
    return int(x_rot), int(y_rot)

def display_image():
    global engine_img

    engine_img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(current_dir, "image.jpg")) # Read the image file - image is a RECTANGLE, not a square.

    if rotation_angle == 0:
        original_width, original_height = engine_img.shape[1], engine_img.shape[0] # Original dimensions when image is in standard position.
        desired_width, desired_height = 920, 690 # Desired dimensions when image is in standard position.

    if rotation_angle == 90 or rotation_angle == -270:
        original_width, original_height = engine_img.shape[0], engine_img.shape[1] # Swap original dimensions, since image has been flipped sideways.
        desired_width, desired_height = 690, 920 # Swap desired dimensions, since image has been flipped sideways.
        engine_img = cv2.rotate(engine_img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

    elif rotation_angle == 180 or rotation_angle == -180:
        original_width, original_height = engine_img.shape[1], engine_img.shape[0] # Image is upside downm, so original dimensions are the same as when in standard position.
        desired_width, desired_height = 920, 690 # Image is upside downm, so desired dimensions are the same as when in standard position.
        engine_img = cv2.rotate(engine_img, cv2.ROTATE_180)

    elif rotation_angle == 270 or rotation_angle == -90:
        original_width, original_height = engine_img.shape[0], engine_img.shape[1] # Swap original dimensions, since image has been flipped sideways.
        desired_width, desired_height = 690, 920 # Swap desired dimensions, since image has been flipped sideways.
        engine_img = cv2.rotate(engine_img, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    engine_img = cv2.resize(engine_img, (desired_width, desired_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA) # Resize the image to desired dimensions.

    image_center_x, image_center_y = int(desired_width / 2), int(desired_height / 2) # Coordinates of point at the center of the image.
    cv2.circle(engine_img, (image_center_x, image_center_y), 5, (0,0,255), 5) # Draw a red circle at the image's center.

    bbox = { # Coordinates of ROI on the image (rectangle).
        "x_min": 2787,
        "y_min": 1385,
        "x_max": 3391,
        "y_max": 1881
    }

    # Adjust coordinates based on the desired image's dimensions.
    x_min = int(bbox.get("x_min", 0) * desired_width / original_width)
    y_min = int(bbox.get("y_min", 0) * desired_height / original_height)
    x_max = int(bbox.get("x_max", 0) * desired_width / original_width)
    y_max = int(bbox.get("y_max", 0) * desired_height / original_height)

    # Function calls to get the position of the ROI after rotation
    x_min_rot, y_min_rot = rotate_point(image_center_x, image_center_y, x_min, y_min, rotation_angle)
    x_max_rot, y_max_rot = rotate_point(image_center_x, image_center_y, x_max, y_max, rotation_angle)

    center_x, center_y = int((x_min_rot + x_max_rot) / 2), int((y_min_rot + y_max_rot) / 2) # Coordinates of point at the center of the ROI on the image.
    cv2.circle(engine_img, (center_x, center_y), 3, (255,0,0), 3) # Draw a blue circle at the ROI's center.

    cv2.namedWindow("Image Viewer", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL) # Open a window.
    cv2.resizeWindow("Image Viewer", engine_img.shape[1], engine_img.shape[0]) # Resize opened window to the image's size.

    cv2.imshow("Image Viewer", engine_img) # Visualize the image on the opened window.

display_image() # Initial call to open the window with the image

while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 27: # Close image window and end program when "ESC" key is pressed.
        break

    if keyboard.is_pressed('up arrow'): # Rotate image 90º clockwise.
        rotation_angle = (rotation_angle + 90) % 360
        display_image()

    if keyboard.is_pressed('down arrow'): # Rotate image 90º counter-clockwise.
        rotation_angle = (rotation_angle - 90) % 360
        display_image()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is a link to the image I'm using:

[image: Here is a link to the image I'm using] - it should be downloaded and put into the same folder directory as the python program and then named "image.jpg".

Comment: Why do you draw the ROI each time. Why not just draw once on the input before rotation? If your problem is the aspect after rotation in the window, then see https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you question, but the point of the image rotation is to, in case the original image is in a poor angle, the user can rotate it to better visualize it. When he rotates it, he should still be able to see the drawn ROIs - otherwise, this wouldn't be a computer vision ROI visualizing functionality, it'd be just a image rotation program.

Comment: formulate the transformation matrix. then apply it to the corner points of your ROI. transformation matrices compose with matrix multiplication. write functions that translate and rotate. then you can rotate around the image center.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have no idea what you're talking about, but I gonna do some research on those terms you mentioned! Thank you for your help

Comment: @toyotaSupra I'm not sure I understand... what exactly would I want to use mouseevent button for in this application?

Comment: Rotate your ROI coordinates with respect to the center of the image. Lots of great web pages that explain how to perform 2D rotation around an arbitrary 2D point.